# SDL support on Android Based and Windows Phone

Tags: android, windows-mobile, sdl, windows-phone-7, game-engine

Where can i find information about Windows Mobile OS or Android.I need to know, if they support SDL or not.

Does all android phone support SDL?

Comment: Do you have *any* idea about what you're talking of?

Answer (score 3):

[Looks like it's possible](http://jiggawatt.org/badc0de/android/index.html#sdl).